# VBA autofill down with variable range method error

Tags: vba

I'm trying to add new columns to the end of the data and autofill a function. Here's my code. I got an error in the autofill part. range of method class failed. Can someone have a look please? Thanks!

```
Sub Geocode()
'Add Lat and Long columns to the end of the report

Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim lastRow As Long


With Sheets("ReportResults 1")
    lastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Cells(1, lastColumn + 1).Value = "Location"
    .Cells(1, lastColumn + 2).Value = "Latitude"
    .Cells(1, lastColumn + 3).Value = "Longitude"

    .Cells(2, lastColumn + 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-17]&"", ""&RC[-16]&"", ""&RC[-15]&"" ""&RC[-14]&"", USA"""

    'auto fill formula
    .Range(lastColumn + 1 & "2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(lastColumn + 1 & "2:" & lastColumn + 1 & lastRow)

    'copay paste value
    Columns(lastColumn + 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: When the error raises, enter debug mode and type `Debug.Print lastColumn + 1 & "2:" & lastColumn + 1 & lastRow` in the Immediate window. What's the result?

Comment: it looks like a typo you have "2:" shouldn't it just be "2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are going to cause a problem because they are not in a proper named range format:

```
.Range(lastColumn + 1 & "2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(lastColumn + 1 & "2:" & lastColumn + 1 & lastRow)
```

Instead try this:

```
.Cells(2, lastColumn + 1).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, lastColumn + 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1))
```

Or even better on a single line:

```
.Cells(2, lastColumn + 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, lastColumn + 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The codes work proper if I switch the position of row and column in the cells like this.     `.Cells(2, lastColumn + 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, lastColumn + 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1))`

Comment: @qshngv - You are right. That's a gaff on my part - I have updated my answer.